# Why didn't Yoda use his lightsaber to block Force lightning?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, revenge-of-the-sith, attack-of-the-clones

In *Attack Of The Clones*, Obi-Wan used his lightsaber to block Count Dooku's Force lightning; Mace Windu did the same thing in *Revenge Of The Sith* to counter Palpatine's. Why didn't Yoda do that in both of his fights, instead of *manually* deflecting or absorbing it? Was it his arrogance, which Palpatine spoke of?

Comment: The first time was a surprise attack, the second time I suspect for cinematic reasons, to show the 'contest' between the light and the dark, mirroring the force push duel between Anakin and Obi-wan on Mustafar. You could also say that Yoda initially tried to block the second force lightning attack with his lightsaber, but he had just jumped on the pod and hadn't had his balance fully so it might have knocked the lightsaber out of his hand. As for why he didn't block it from Dooku, maybe he couldn't pull his saber out in time as he didn't expect Dooku to know how to do it.

Comment: Yoda did it purely to show mastery of the force against dooku. The dialogue fully implies as much. Id Imagine Yoda also wanted a simple test of force strength against palpatine, which Yoda either decided they were dead equal or he yoda was at least not in a place to have advantage on Plpatine.

Comment: he did it so the movie directors could drop the bomb "you can block force lightning without a lightsaber!!!"

Answer (score 6):

> Why didn't Yoda do that in both of his fights, instead of manually deflecting or absorbing it?

Yoda was not wielding his lightsaber in either of the fights when he was attacked with force lightning.

In the case of Obi-Wan and Windu, they were both already wielding their lightsabers when they were attacked with force lightning which is why they used it.

Perhaps the quick nature of a force lightning attack is such that Yoda would not have had enough time to wield his lightsaber in order to defend himself.  It looks like he did not even have time to defend himself against Palpatine's attack.

Comment: Because it looks cool